# Image Width Percentage [ CSS ]

Tags: html, css, asp.net, width, bootstrap-4

I used bootstrap on my asp.net page. But unfortunately, I have encountered a problem using percentage in width attribute. When I used pixel then it is working but when I used percentage will not work. Please see image below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please try to give some code...?

Comment: Why do you need to use % ? If there have nothing special , just use pixel

Comment: try 100%or 200% and see if its even working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `pull-right` class from the `member-role` element and try to use columns to align the items.

Answer (score 0):

Original Code

```
<div class="big-box">

    <div class="member-info">

        <img src="img/team/store.png" alt="admin" class="img-circle" />
        <span class="member-name"><%# Eval("cust_name") %></span>
        <div class="member-role red pull-right">

            <div class="progress">
               <div style="width: 40%;" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ></div>     

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Removing PULL-RIGHT (thanks @hunzaboy)

```
<div class="big-box">

    <div class="member-info">

        <img src="img/team/store.png" alt="admin" class="img-circle" />
        <span class="member-name"><%# Eval("cust_name") %></span>
        <div class="member-role red">

            <div class="progress">
               <div style="width: 40%;" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ></div>     

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

**Thanks for the help guys. Appreciated Much. :)**

Answer (score -1):

Percentages are calculated using the size of the parent element. I'm guessing that the div that your element is nested in doesn't have any set width.

Comment: This should be a Comment